# Django Ajax field help

Tags: ajax, django

I have a Django application where I'm trying to have a form that populates a drop down dynamically based on a previous dropdown.

simplified Models:

```
class VehicleMake(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length = 30)


class VehicleModel(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    make = models.ForeignKey(VehicleMake)

class Listing(models.Model):
    make = models.ForeignKey(VehicleMake)
    model = models.ForeignKey(VehicleModel)
```

Form:

```
class DynamicChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def clean(self, value):
        return value

class MyForm(ModelForm):
    category = ModelChoiceField(VehicleCategory.objects, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange':'FilterMakes();'}))
    make = DynamicChoiceField(VehicleMake.objects,widget=forms.Select(attrs={'disabled':'true','onchange':'FilterModels();'}), empty_label="Select Model")
    model = DynamicChoiceField(VehicleModel.objects,widget=forms.Select(attrs={'disabled':'true'}), empty_label="Select Make")


    class Meta:
        model = Listing
```

View:

```
def new_listing(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    else:
        form = MyForm()



    return render_to_response("newlisting.html", {
        "form": form,'model_id':model_id,'make_id':make_id
    })
```

I also have some ajax defined for the auto-populate but this is not the problem

When I submit the form I get the following:

```
Cannot assign "u'2'": "Listing.make" must be a "VehicleMake" instance.
```

if I try

```
make=VehicleMake.objects.get(pk=request.POST['make'])
form.fields['make'] = make
```

then I get

```
'VehicleMake' object has no attribute 'widget'
```

Comment: perhaps your ajax *is* the problem. Maybe you should post your template & js.

Comment: Although the problem could well lie with DynamicChoiceField - the cut-down code you've posted doesn't really show what it does. I wish people would post real code.

Comment: Dustin - the Ajax portion works it's when the form submits that it's only taking the value from the select and it's not instantiating as an instance of the VehicleMake class

Comment: Daniel - that is the whole DynamicChoiceField the only reason the class exists is to override the clean function not over riding it and using a ModelChoiceField causes an error in the validation

Comment: I should have noted that this code is based on Dustin's example here

http://www.nerdydork.com/dynamic-filtered-drop-down-choice-fields-with-django.html

The Major difference being that instead of extending forms.Form and forms.ChoiceField I'm extending forms.ModelForm and forms.ModelChoiceField

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the suggestion of one of the commenter's that the DynamicChoiceField class was the culprit I removed it and set the form objects for ModelChoiceFields with the exact same other parameters. The object appears to pass and validate correctly as well. The extra class existed based on an old tutorial I found. it appears that what the author did there works with the forms.ChoiceField but is not required for using a ModelChoiceField

thanks everyone for the help